# ASP: runat=server for dynamic control

Tags: asp.net, runatserver

In the Page_Load method I create a couple of controls, based on various conditions. I would like to register server side code with those controls. However, for the last part I need to declare my controls as server controls. This is normally done by runat=server, but I don't know how to set this attribute in the C# code. myControl.Attributes.Add("runat", "server") does not do the trick. This one works, meaning that the "test" method is called when I click on it:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="test">testtext</asp:LinkButton>
```

This one does not work:

```
            LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();
            lb.ID = "LinkButton1";
            lb.OnClientClick = "test";
            lb.Text = "testtext";
            lb.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
```

I can click on it, and the page is loaded, but the test-method is not called.

Any hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost got it right. Just a couple things:

- When you manually instantiate a server control, there's no need to add the `runat="server"` attribute. This is a special attribute that's used only by the ASP.NET page parser to distinguish server controls from other markup.
- The `OnClick` attribute in markup corresponds to the `Click` server-side event, which you hook up using the `+=` operator. (On the other hand, the `OnClientClick` attribute in markup corresponds to the `onclick` *client-side* attribute, which typically contains a snippet of JavaScript code. The fact that `OnClick` doesn't correspond to `onclick` is admittedly a bit confusing.)

Thus:

```
LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();
lb.ID = "LinkButton1";
lb.Click += test;
lb.Text = "testtext";
```

And your event handler (which you can even make `private` if there are no references to it from markup):

```
protected void test(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. That works. Now, if I add a regular button (<asp:Button runat="server" ID="submit" Text="query" />), the click on my previous linkbutton does not trigger anything (no page load). If the asp:Button is not on the page, everything works like a charm. Any clues?

Comment: When you say that the LinkButton doesn't trigger anything, do you mean that the page still refreshes (but the LinkButton's event handler isn't called), or does the page not refresh at all? Also, in what method are you adding the LinkButton to the page?

Comment: I am adding the LinkButton in Page_Load. The asp:Button is in the .aspx file. And yes, the page does not refresh at all. As soon as I remove the asp:Button everything works as before.

Comment: That's certainly very strange. If the page doesn't even post back when you click the LinkButton, then the only reasons I can think of are (1) there's a form validation error and (2) there's a JavaScript error.

Comment: You might also try adding lb to your server control:  this.Controls.Add(lb);  I had to do this for my events to fire.  Also, I'm no pro when it comes to page life cycle, but I tend to declare my dynamic controls in the constructor.  That way I know they exist by the time the page gets around to raising click events.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to register server side event? If so you can do like this.

```
LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();
lb.ID = "LinkButton1";
lb.Click += new EventHandler(LinkButton1_Click);
lb.Text = "testtext";
```

Event

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to. Since the controls are created on the server side via C# code, they are already server-side controls. The problem you are experiencing has to do with the page life cycle: when you create a control on the server side as you are doing now, you need to re-add the control on every postback and rehook any event handlers that you want to handle for them.

Also note that your code shows 2 different things: on the markup that you posted, you are displaying a handler for the `OnClick` event whereas on the C# code you are adding a handler for the `OnClientClick` event. They are 2 different things. The `OnClientClick` event simply fires any javascript code that you have on your page when the control is clicked. It's exactly the same as doing this:

```
 link.Attributes.Add("onclick","SomeJavascriptFunction();");
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, you don't need that `lb.Attributes.Add("runat", "server")` line. All `runat="server"` does is make the control visible to the code-behind. Since you're adding the control in the code-behind, that's a moot point.

<strike>As for the script, note that the one that works is using `OnClick` and your broken one is using `OnClientClick`. The difference is important because `OnClick` is natively understood by javascript, and it will find the function with the name `test` and execute it.</strike>

`OnClientClick`, on the other hand, is arbitrary javascript that the ASP.NET runtime binds to the click event manually. Meaning, it's just going to execute `test`. That's nothing. `test()`, on the other hand, is proper javascript.

So, change that line to `lb.OnClickClick = "test()";`

edit: I mixed myself up, see the other answer.