# Making a Control to be runat=server

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, button, dynamic-controls, runatserver

In my application I have created a button dynamically & its name is "Dynamic_Button". Is it possible to make the button to be `runat=server`. I just tried the code but it doesn't work.

```
Dynamic_Button.Attributes.Add("runat","server");
```

Is there anyother ways to make it in serverside ?

Comment: What are you using? ASP.NET?

Comment: All _server_ controls are `runat=server` implicitely in ASP.NET.

Comment: This is not what you want to do, you need to add the control dynamically to the page. And it would be runat server automaticaly. I will give you an example soon.

Comment: Do you need to have an example of how to add a Dynamic Button to a container like a Panel? Or did you do that already?

Comment: _What_ is `Dynamic_Button`?

Answer (score 0):

When you manually instantiate a server control, there's no need to add the runat="server" attribute. This is a special attribute that's used only by the ASP.NET page parser to distinguish server controls from other markup.

The OnClick attribute in markup corresponds to the Click server-side event, which you hook up using the += operator.

So:

```
LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();
lb.ID = "LinkButton1";
lb.Click += click_event;
lb.Text = "testtext";
```

And the event handler

```
protected void click_event(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

In this example there is no need to add runat server because it already has it.

Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11337397/284240

Comment: Yep, and cleaned it a bit.

Comment: It's ok to quote another answer if you add the reference(what you've done now), but the answer is still a little bit off-topic since OP has no `LinkButton` and he also don't ask how to add a click-event programmatically.

Comment: Yes you are right, but I want to show that is not needed to add a runat server attribute.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://shahed-kazi.blogspot.in/2009/07/dynamically-add-button-control-to.html) and [this](http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2012/07/dynamic-button-controls-clickevent.html)  will guide you in creating and adding buttons at run time as well assigning events(client and server side).