# Find generated HTML Control and assign value to it

Tags: html, asp.net, .net, vb.net

Hello i generate HTML input text controls with a string builder and put it inside a div from Code Behind.

Then i also need to assign values to these generated input & update database if values change by the user.

The problem is Code Behind can't find the generated from String builder HTML Input-text Controls
You can see code example below:

```
Public Class WebForm1
        Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
        Private Sub WebForm1_PreInit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.PreInit
            Dim strB As New StringBuilder
            For i = 0 To 5
                strB.Append("<input type=""text"" value="""" runat=""server"" id=position_" & i & "/>")
            Next
            wraper.InnerHtml = strB.ToString
            strB.Clear()
        End Sub
        Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
            For i = 0 To 5
                Dim a As HtmlInputText
                a = Me.Page.FindControl("position_" & i)
                a.Value = "test"
            Next
        End Sub
    End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're not creating controls, you're creating strings without a context.
You might want to look at these questions:

[ASP: runat=server for dynamic control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11337268/asp-runat-server-for-dynamic-control)

[Dynamically Created Controls losing data after postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17589268/dynamically-created-controls-losing-data-after-postback)